# Unregister your device from a WiFi network

Tags: wifi, captive-portal

Recently, I connected my Android device to an open wi-fi network. Then a web page opened up asking me to choose username and password to log in with. Now when I connect the same device to that network, the web page doesn't open up anymore and the phone automatically logs into with the chosen credentials.

Is there a way to make the network believe that my phone has never connected to it before, so that I can log in using different credentials?

Comment: It is unclear how exactly you connected your device to the WiFi network and where exactly was the dialog. And it is unclear how exactly the network remembers you. It might simply be based on MAC address, in which case you would need to change this (how to do this is off-topic, please use search engine). But it could also be done in the captive portal and there are the many various ways of user tracking, like cookies.

Answer (score 2):

The wifi access point is probably recognizing your android device's MAC address, which normally remains constant, even throughout power-cycles.

If you want the wifi access point to 'believe you are a new user', you may be able to temporarily change your MAC address.  See https://www.techjunkie.com/change-mac-address-android/ for more info.